# python stacked bar plot with multiple items per stack

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas `df` as follows:

```
TYPE      CAR     COUNT
Sedan    Honda     50
Sedan   Toyota     100
Sedan   Mazda      25
SUV     Honda      10
SUV     Toyota     25
SUV    Mazda       50
```

I am looking to build a stacked bar chart with:

1. `TYPE` on the x-axis
2. `CAR` and `COUNT` on the y-axis with `COUNT` governing the size of the bar. So we would have 2 bars, one for `Sedan` and one for `SUV` each having 3 colored stacks and in the case of `Sedan` the size of the bar for `Toyota` would be 4 times the size of `Mazda` and twice that of `Honda`
   How can I do this in either `seaborn` or `matplotlib`?
   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching, [Stacked bar using group by in Python dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68198102/stacked-bar-using-group-by-in-python-dataframe) answered my question...hence closing this!